# Denormalize images from [0 1] to [0 255]

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision

after performing this during inferencing/testing:

```
output = model(image)
output = output.cpu().detach().numpy()
output = np.squeeze(output , axis = 0)
```

I tried to denormalize the output by using my own function:

```
def Denormaliser3Channel (image):
    image = image.swapaxes(2,0)  # <--- from (Channel, H, W) to (H, W, Channel)
    mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
    std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
    
    image = image*std
    image = image + mean
    image = (image)*255.
                 
    return image
```

after using the function, this is the result of the image array:

```
[[[126.09467533 120.49761354  95.68051658]
  [126.04139193 120.18946077  95.76008117]
  [126.0490471  120.06061473  95.65981557]
  ...
```

what operations do I need to perform/missing so that the output is in int? such as:

```
[[[126  120  95]
  [126  120  95]
  [126  120  95]
  ...
```

Comment: did you try `image.round().astype('uint8')`?

Comment: Oh, by the way, you may want to just do `image.astype('uint8')` since `np.array([255.6]).round()` gives `256`.